# React Native Expo make call, send SMS or Email

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

How can I make calls or send SMS and Email messages with React Native Expo framework?

I am contemplating between using Expo or not and one of the concerns - support of some third-party libs. Typically with react native you would use well written [Communications library](https://github.com/anarchicknight/react-native-communications). Can I use it with Expo project or I should use something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The react-native-communications library would work just fine with Expo -- it is just JavaScript and depends on the "Linking" API. If you're curious about why this works, you can see some more information on how Linking works in Expo in the [Linking guide](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/linking.html). But go ahead and use react-native-communications if that covers your use case!

Comment: Just found it! Thanks!

Comment: @brentvatne I am trying to use react-native-communications for sending SMS with Expo, but the application crashes (android Genymotion emulator on Windows), with the following error: 
"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.endsWith(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference".  

The code is: 
"import Comm from 'react-native-communications';" 
and 
"Comm.text('123456789', 'msg');"

I also tried "Comm.text('sms:+123456789', 'msg');", same error. 

Did you do anything else?

Comment: Apparently you might have needed to use the non-standard `tel://...` (at least with certain versions of React Native?): https://stackoverflow.com/a/50628917/495319

Comment: Have just tried the following on an Android phone and it works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60347445/495319