# Cannot open phone call with Linking.openURL

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-linking

### Description

Cannot open phone call with Linking.openURL('tel:+123456789')

### Environment

Environment:
  OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4
  Node: 8.5.0
  Yarn: Not Found
  npm: 5.8.0
  Watchman: Not Found
  Xcode: Xcode 9.3 Build version 9E145
  Android Studio: 2.3 AI-162.4069837

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.3.1 => 16.3.1
  react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-27.0.0.tar.gz => 0.55.2
  expo: 27.0.1,

### Steps to Reproduce

```
import ...
export default class App extends React.Component {

_pressCall=()=>{
    const url='tel:+123456789'
    Linking.openURL(url)
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button title='call' onPress={this._pressCall}/>
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

https://snack.expo.io/@kikoololmdrxdd/test-linking-phone-call

### Expected Behavior

open phone call

### Actual Behavior

```
[Android]Error message
attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.string.endsWith(java.
lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: I found a solution: you need to convert 'tel:' to 'tel://'

Comment: Thanks a lot, you save my day

Comment: Thanks, you should post the answer and mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found a solution: you need to convert 'tel:' to 'tel://'

Comment: ` if (/tel\:/.test(navState.url)) {
            Linking.openURL(`tel://${navState.url.split('tel:').pop()}`)
            this._webViewRef.stopLoading()
        }`
I am using this code but still, my app is crashing.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Do you maybe know why you need the prompt to be with `//` now? On iOS it works fine without them, just not on Android. The official RN docs also show the `tel:` one so it's strange.

Comment: iOS seems to need the // now on RN 0.71.8

Comment: Look for RFC 3966 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966#section-3 - there is no double slash in the URI syntax.

Answer (score 9):

`tel:` worked on Android

`tel://` worked on Iphone

Answer (score 2):

`tel://` works for iPhone and Android. `RN 0.61`

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me I found a solution: you need to convert 'tel:' to 'tel://'

Linking.openURL(`tel://${phone}`)