# Is it possible open mail or phone call with Linking.openURL in react native?

Tags: react-native

I need to make a call when I click on the button, or open mail in order to send a message, we usually use the a tag with the necessary `mail:` or `tel:` attributes for these purposes, but is it possible to do this using `Linking.openURL` like this?

```
onPress={() => Linking.openURL('+380775454545455')
```

If it possible, what should we add in order to do it?

Comment: There is already same question and solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272908/cannot-open-phone-call-with-linking-openurl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mail:

```
const subject = "Mail Subject";
const message = "Message Body";
Linking.openURL(`mailto:support@domain.com?subject=${subject}&body=${message}`)
```

Phone call:

```
const phone = "+380775454545455";
Linking.openURL(`tel:${phone}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

As referred to in the react-native's [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#built-in-url-schemes) you can open your mail or make a phone call using the Linking component.

Phone call:

```js
const phoneNumber = "+123456789";
Linking.openURL(`tel:${phoneNumber}`);
```

Email:

```js
const email = "support@expo.io";

// if you want to just open the mail app
Linking.openURL(`mailto:${email}`);

// if you want to open the mail app with subject and body
const subject = "Subject";
const body = "Body";

Linking.openURL(`mailto:${email}?subject=${subject}&body=${body}`);
```

You can also use the component to open a website, send an SMS, or even open other apps through Deep Linking. For further explanation please see the documentation