# Linking.openURL('tel:xxxxx') doens't work in React Native iOS 0.72 iOS

Tags: react-native

The following `Linking.openURL` method

```
const phone_number = '(800) 321 123 122'
Linking.openURL(`tel:${phone_number}`)
```

is not working on React Native 0.72, but worked on some earlier versions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot open phone call with Linking.openURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272908/cannot-open-phone-call-with-linking-openurl)

Answer (score 2):

One needs to add // to prefix, e.g.

```
Linking.openURL(`tel://${phone_number}`) 
Linking.openURL(`maps://...`)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `Linking.openURL()` on iOS now doesn't accept spaces (at least in "tel:"). Just add:
`Linking.openURL(´tel:${phone_number.replaceAll(' ','')}´)`