# Expo Permission PHONE_CALL

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Hi i am trying to create a react native with expo app the main app's function is call users in an automatic way but we are not able to request PHONE_CALL permission using expo! what is the best way to call any Android permission?

The app is only Android but we don´t know how to request this permission!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Linking.openURL` for this:

```
Linking.openURL('tel:123456789');
```

Here is an example of it in action: https://snack.expo.io/@notbrent/ashamed-churros

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Linking, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text
        onPress={() => {
          Linking.openURL('tel:50000000');
        }}>
        Call some phone
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```